# How to sum the previous pandas df column with the current if it contains the word "extra"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df that has columns that need to be summed with to the previous column iff they contain the word "extra". For example, here is my pandas df:

```
id    laptops  laptops extra  battery  cables  monitor monitor extra
0     54       18             108      54      28      12   
1     33       9              48       20      10      4
2     82       61             98       67      21      9
...
```

Is there a way in pandas to find columns that contain the word extra and sum them with the previous column? That would help clean up so much data.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide us with code you made so far?

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `extra` text and aggregate `sum` for all columns:

```
df1 = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' extra', ''))
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1, sort=False)
         .sum())
```

Or filter `extra` columns, remove  `extra` and add to original columns, last remove `extra` columns:

```
m = df.columns.str.endswith('extra')

df1 = (df.add(df.loc[:, m]
              .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' extra', '')), axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .loc[:, ~m])
```

EDIT: For add previous column by `extra` substring in end of columns names use:

```
m = df.columns.to_series().str.endswith('extra')

df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)] + df.loc[:, m].to_numpy()
df = df.loc[:, ~m]
print (df)
    id  laptops  battery  cables  monitor
0  0.0     54.0    108.0    54.0     28.0
1  1.0     33.0     48.0    20.0     10.0
2  2.0     82.0     98.0    67.0     21.0
```